# Can an arraylist be initialized with a method returned arraylist?

Tags: java, android, syntax, arraylist

Quite new to the Java language, I was wondering whether it is correct and possible to do this:

```
ArrayList<PeopleDetails> people_SMS = checkbox_SMS(adapter);
```

Where checkbox_SMS(adapter) is a method that returns type ArrayList. 
Is this legitimate code, or will the people_SMS arraylist merely contain a pointer to the the returned arraylist? Will my code work, if I want to access the data from checkbox_SMS?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Yes. You can initialize. (indirectly you are referencing to the ArrayList that is returned from the method...

Comment: It's a method that returns - ArrayList<PeopleDetails> - that's all that is needed to answer the question... I hope :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`people_SMS` arraylist will merely be a pointer to the the returned arraylist. If you want to create a new list that is a copy of the returned, use

```
ArrayList<PeopleDetails> people_SMS = new ArrayList<>(checkbox_SMS(adapter));
```

Comment: thanks, this is what I was looking for. I only want to read the contents of the arraylist, but I assume this allows me to manipulate them as well? Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1):

It can work as long as `checkbox_SMS` returns an instance of `ArrayList<PeopleDetails>`.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering whether it is correct and possible to do this:

```
ArrayList<PeopleDetails> people_SMS = checkbox_SMS(adapter);
```

That's a completely valid line  If your checkbox_sms method returning a `ArrayList.`. And you can use it furthur

> will the people_SMS arraylist merely contain a pointer to the the returned arraylist?

Yes, it is as you are initializing with returned list.

> Will my code work, if I want to access the data from checkbox_SMS?

Yes, it is.

Make sure that it is not returning a `null`, before using it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a valid code. Inside your `checkbox_SMS` method you should create an instance of `ArrayList<PeopleDetails>` and return it.

It is also possible to return `null` form such a method and the code will be valid too. In such cases, you should check if `people_SMS` is not null before using it.